# How to add bc to bitbucket CI?

Tags: bitbucket, sh, bitbucket-pipelines, bc

I am adding `pylint` to Bitbucket CI. I decided to move with the custom scripts.

`bitbucket-pipeline.yml` is the following:

```
image: python:3.6.2

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - pip
        script:
          - set -e
          - pip install -r requirements.txt
          - pip install --upgrade urllib3
          - nosetests project1/test
          - nosetests project2/test
          - pylint --rcfile=.pylintrc --output-format=text project1/report | tee pylint.txt
          - score=$(sed -n 's/^Your code has been rated at \([-0-9.]*\)\/.*/\1/p' pylint.txt)
          - apt-get install bc
          - sh pylint_score.sh
```

The script for checking `pylint` score (`pylint_score.sh`) is below:

```
#!/usr/sh

score=$(sed -n 's/^Your code has been rated at \([-0-9.]*\)\/.*/\1/p' pylint.txt)

echo "Pylint score was $score"

threshhold=$(echo "$score>8.0" | bc)

echo "$threshhold"

if [ $threshhold -eq 0 ]
then
    exit 1
fi

exit 0
```

The error I am getting:

> E: Unable to locate package bc

How can I install `bc` into Bitbucket CI or there is any workaround to get it work without `bc` at all?

Initially, I looked on different solutions but it seems that there are neither out-of-the-box solution nor "best practice" guy that everyone implements. Therefore, I moved with my custom implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve my issue, I found [Bitbucket ticket](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Bitbucket-pipeline-apt-get-update-and-install/qaq-p/705340).

In`bitbucket-pipeline.yml`:

`apt-get install bc` line should be modified to

`apt-get update && apt-get install -y bc`

or in some cases to

`apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends bc`

Comment: You can also build your own Docker image that includes bc - that can save you build minutes, since you won't have to wait for `apt` every time.